# IIS6 SMTP Server stops for no reason?

Tags: iis-6, smtp

I am not sure if anyone else has seen this, but I have the SMTP server configured for IIS6. I am not running exchange, by the way, just the regular SMTP server that comes with windows server 2003 and IIS6. For some reason my SMTP server stops and nothing is in the logs about it. I restart it and a few days later it stops again. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the service set to Automatic or Manual startup?  What recovery options is the service set to?

Comment: Also, this will probably get moved to stackoverflow.

Comment: It was set to manual. There were no recovery options. I set that up. It has been so long since I have delt with the IIS side of things I forgot about that stuff. Thanks!!!!!

Comment: @phoebus Yes, mine too was set to Manual. Hopefully this will solve the problem. Thanks for the input

Comment: You can get a look in the administration logs...

Answer (score 1):

We have seen this issue before on one of our test servers.
It turned out that an IIS update/windows Update caused an issues with an out of date Anti Virus Email Scan engine.  Even though the anti virus patterns were up to date the scan engine/av program was old and causing the SMTP service to hang and crash.

Hopefully this is the same issue for you.

Answer (score 1):

We found that doing the following worked, and can now edit the settings in the II6 Manager without errors (and without crashing when applying settings) every time:

1. Stop SMTPSVC service [Display Name: Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP)]
2. Stop IISADMIN service [Display name: IIS Admin Service]
3. Edit "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\MetaBase.xml"
4. Find: <IIsSmtpServer Location ="/LM/SmtpSvc/1"
5. Add (Settings are alphabetical): RelayIpList=""
6. Save file
7. Start IISAdmin Service
8. Start SMTPSVC service

You can now open the Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0 Manager (InetMgr6.exe) and work like normal. The setting above relates to the Access Tab > Relay Restrictions section, but doesn't set anything in it (i.e. "all except the below list" with a blank list).

After setting this value you can change it to what you need it to be. (i.e. the value doesn't need to be 'null' for the fix to work, just so long as the variable is present in the file).

The above has been tested on a few new installs of Windows Server 2022, and has worked for us every time. If you have done an upgrade there are some other things to consider (seems like the SMTP service is not installed after upgrade so will require a backup of the settings that can be applied post reinstalling the service. But that is discussed in other topics).

PS: Remember to set the SMTPSVC service to start "automatically". By default its set to "manual".

Source: https://serverfault.com/questions/1088555/server-2022-smtp-server-issue

Comment: i'm using windows server 2019 and this solution not worked for me